# How do I make this code automatically run every 5 minutes so that the video title matches the views even if I turn off my computer?

Tags: javascript, api, cron, youtube

So I have followed a tutorial to change the title of a Youtube video to match the views. Now the tutorial was talking about stuff like cronjobs but didn't specify how to use them. I'm a beginner so I don't know much about this. My code works, but I have to rerun the code every 5 minutes so that the title matches the views.
So can someone help me set up cronjobs or whatever is required to make the code run even after I shut down my computer.

```
require('dotenv').config()

var {google} = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
const VIDEO_ID = process.env.VIDEO_ID

main()

async function main() {
  try {
    const auth = authorize()
    const videoViews = await getVideoViews(auth)
    const videoTitle = await updateVideoTitle(auth, videoViews)
    console.log(videoTitle)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

function authorize() {
  const credentials = JSON.parse(process.env.CLIENT_SECRET)
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(process.env.OAUTH_TOKEN);
  return oauth2Client
}

function getVideoViews(auth) {
  const service = google.youtube('v3')
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    service.videos.list({
      auth: auth,
      part: 'statistics',
      id: VIDEO_ID
    }, function(err, response) {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      resolve(response.data.items[0].statistics.viewCount)
    })
  })
}

function updateVideoTitle(auth, views) {
  const service = google.youtube('v3')
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    service.videos.update({
      auth: auth,
      part: 'snippet',
      resource: {
        id: VIDEO_ID,
        snippet: {
          title: `This Video Has ${new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(views)} Views`,
          categoryId: 27
        }
      }
    }, function(err, response) {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      resolve(response.data.snippet.title)
    })
  })
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the operating system you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can call your `main` function recursively every 5 minutes using `setTimeout` something like this:

```
async function main() {
  try {
    const auth = authorize()
    const videoViews = await getVideoViews(auth)
    const videoTitle = await updateVideoTitle(auth, videoViews)
    console.log(videoTitle)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
   setTimeout(main, 5*60*1000);
}
```

But note that, this won't work if the computer is turned off as there's no API call will be made in that case. To make it perpetually work you need to deploy the code on a server which is up 24*7

Comment: Can you please tell which servers do that, and how to deploy codes on it?

Comment: Server is just another machine just like yours which is always up. If you can keep your system on always, it can act like a server. For practical cases, you may use something like github pages to deploy this application.

Comment: So what about cronjobs? Can they do this work? Please tell me how do I set them up.

Comment: AFAI,  setTimeout will do the job for you here. You can try and see. Cron jobs are time-based schedulers which perform some actions periodically. You can read more at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: No, I mean how will I host this for free, do I have to use cronjobs or something. Thanks for all the help though.

Comment: You can host this on github pages for free. https://pages.github.com/ (if this answer works and does the job every minute 5 min, you may not need cronjobs)
For more professional deployments you may go for AWS/Godaddy which charge.